# How to use TODO and FIXME in Latexila?

Tags: editors

I am using Latexila 2.4 on Ubuntu 12.10. In the GUI there is an option to view TODO and FIXME (green tick on my screenshot), but I have no idea how I can mark up text in the source so it would show up there.

I could not find any reference on the web either.

How to use TODO in Latexila?

[image]

Comment: maybe it is marked automatically if you use the `todonotes` package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TODO` and `FIXME` are "magic" comments, if you write e.g.

```
%TODO Something you have to do later.
```

or

```
%FIXME This is clearly wrong.
```

and refresh the side panel, they will show up. The comments will also be highlighted in the text.

[image]

Comment: Splendid! That is exactly what I want! Thanks!